# increase of number with for in loop

Tags: swift

My goal is to increase my jackpot counter everytime the user diced the number 6.
I already tried using a for in loop like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var numberDisplayLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var jackpotCountLabel: UILabel!



@IBAction func diceRollBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var count = 0
    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform((10)+1)
    if randomNumber == 6 {
        numberDisplayLabel.text = "Jackpot!!! You got \(randomNumber)!"
        for count in 0..==6 {
            jackpotCountLabel.text = "Jackpot count: \(count)"
        }
    } else {
        numberDisplayLabel.text = "Unlucky! Maybe next time."
    }
}
```

But it seems that I can't use `==` as an operator to check the condition.
Is a for in loop even appropriate for a task like this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, please explain.

Comment: With 'arc4random_uniform((10)+1)' I'm trying to generate a random number. If the number is 6, the user "won". I'm trying to increase a counter everytime the user diced 6, so the user can see how much times he already diced 6.

Comment: I got that, but that's not where your problem lies, right? So explain your problem. Why the for loop? What do you mean by increasing the counter?

Comment: use 0...6 (three dots in the middle) instead of 0..==6

Comment: 1. Because 'for counter = 0; counter == 6; counter++ { ... }' doesn't work anymore I searched for a different way to increase a var everytime a certain condition is given. I finally found a thread on stackoverflow where a user solved this problem with a for in loop. 2. And by increasing the counter I mean the following: I have a label which displays a number. The number should increase everytime the user diced 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several points:

You display `\(randomNumber)` even though it is always equal to 6.

There's no such operator as ..==.

`count` appears to be a count of the number of jackpot wins but it is always set to zero each time the button is pressed.  The `count` variable needs to be stored outside the function and incremented each time the function is called, before it is displayed to the user.

I suggest the following changes...

```
var count = 0
@IBAction func diceRollBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform((10)+1)
    if randomNumber == 6 {
        numberDisplayLabel.text = "Jackpot!!! You got 6!"
        count += 1
        jackpotCountLabel.text = "Jackpot count: \(count)"
    } else {
        numberDisplayLabel.text = "Unlucky! Maybe next time."
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vince O'Sullivan, thank you for your answer. This solved my problem. Wish you a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the same as Vince´s answer, but utilizing the property observer `didSet` instead. In some cases it could be very handy to use this feature when you always want to show the latest variable value in a label, and you don't want to add `label.text = "new string"` everywhere you are changing the variable.

```
var count = 0 {

    didSet {

        self.jackpotCountLabel.text = "Jackpot count: \(count)"
    }
}

var randomNumber: UInt32 = 0 {

    didSet {

        if randomNumber == 6 {

            numberDisplayLabel.text = "Jackpot!!! You got \(randomNumber)!"

            count += 1

            return
        }

        numberDisplayLabel.text = "Unlucky! Maybe next time."
    }
}

@IBAction func diceRollBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    randomNumber = arc4random_uniform((10)+1)
}
```

[Swift 3.1 Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254)

Comment: I like it.  That's a nicely structured answer.  My only comment would be that although the abstraction is good it may confuse a beginner.

Comment: Thank you. I'm hopeful that the initial confusion will lead beginners into the depths of the swift documentation so they are able to unlock their inner guru.